# PHP - Methodology to prevent spam flooding and also excessive bandwidth

Tags: php, spam, bandwidth, flooding

Hi
I am at prototype stage. 
For the scenario below, I want to share my plan with you and I am asking your opinions if my plan makes sense or is there any better way to achieve my requirement that you may recommend. 
thanks, regards
**SCENARIO**
A spam bot can haunt my forms. (mail, comment, article sharing) At the verification stage, I can detect if it’s a spammer by known methods. (captcha, time limit, secret question, hidden form element etc.) but what if the spam boy tries and tries continuously? It won’t able to validate and excute the form aim but it’ll consume the bandwidth continuously. 
**MY REQUIREMENT**
Not only prevent to execute the form aim but also prevent bandwidth consumption on a continuous base. 
**MY PLAN**
Using session abilities, count the number of attempts of the specific ip in a limited time. If the number of attempts is greater than n in x minutes, then redirect the visitor to a totally different url or ban the visitor ip at run-time with php codes. 
**MY QUESTIONS**

1. Is it logical to redirect the spammer to a totally different url? If
   yes do you know any web page that welcomes the spammer IPs in order
   to add them to their blacklists? In other way I am aware that this
   activity will not be ethical so I must not apply this kind of
   redirection.
2. Is it possible to ban an ip at php runtime in my related
   verification pages?

Answer (score 1):

1) It seems illogical to me. For example imagine brute-force bot that would try to get through your captcha. Most propably it will not even run in a web browser. If you send redirect headers, it might just ignore them and not load the target page. If you really need to save bandwidth, you could simply print blank page (for example you could use `exit()`)

2)It is possible to ban ip anytime, you allways have `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` variable and if you decide to ban the ip, you can just add it to database (or file). And whenever somebody needs to be verified, you can query the database for their ip.